# how to get mysql database connection in android emulator

Tags: mysql, android, emulation

How to get the MySQL database connection in android emulator? I try to connect using `java.sql.*` package like this

I get the exception: `java.sql.SQLException:no suitable drive`

How can I use sql packages in android mobile?

Comment: You might have forgotten to put actual code after "like this"...

Comment: This is the 7th or 8th time you've asked this question.  How about editing your previous questions instead of asking over and over?

Answer (score 3):

[As I wrote a few minutes ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256082/best-way-to-implement-client-server-database-architecture-in-an-android-a):

> Never never never use a database
>   driver across an Internet connection,
>   for any database, for any platform,
>   for any client, anywhere. That goes
>   double for mobile. Database drivers
>   are designed for LAN operations and
>   are not designed for
>   flaky/intermittent connections or high
>   latency.

Comment: ok thanks. do u know how to get the value from mysql database using web service an android mobile.  please give some example.

Comment: To access REST Web services from Android, I recommend HttpClient -- you can find sample code on the Apache HttpClient site (http://hc.apache.org).

Answer (score 0):

The way I got around this was writing all the server side code in PHP and inventing my own XML schema for sending and receiving data.  You just use POST or GET and send using the default HTTP classes that come with android.  You can then translate the response XML from the PHP page to do what you want by using one of the three XML parsers that come with android.

Answer (score 0):

You would not typically want to connect directly to a database over
the web on your mobile device.

Instead of connecting directly to a database over the web you might look at creating an interface for whatever data it is you want to access and exposing it as a service:

1. SOAP (ksoap2 )
2. REST

Then you can use Java APIs to access your data.