# connect to sql server from android

Tags: android

I'm currently developing a Field-Service application that stores data in the local sqlite database on an android device. At some point, usually after completing the data collection rounds, the local sqlite db is to be synchronized to a remote sql server db on the server, also i need to update some  local table from sql server db.

Any suggestions as to how this could be achieved or engineered as a solution? Or even better, are there alternatives to synchronizing data in such an application?

Comment: Even am Doing the Same Project, let me Know if you get the Code working

Answer (score 22):

I think that the best is using a intermediary like web services or your own TCP based logic layer for your application which would connect to SQL server and execute requests of your applicatation. Don't try to connect to your SQL server directly from Android. You can write 
some backend code on your server (or webservice) and then call those code methods from your android device using Http.

And also there are many themes in **stackoverflow** like your:

- [How to connect Android to a database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419697/how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server)
- [Connecting android with MS SQL SERVER 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5255984/connecting-android-with-ms-sql-server-2008)

About how to write web services. It's a big question, and you must choose technology, there are very many libraries, frameworks and platforms that help you to simply write a web service. You must choose communicating protocol, it may be SOAP, WSDL or maybe remove calling procedure, it may be rest application. If you use java stack, there are some popular frameworks at the moment:

- [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/)
- [Spring Web Services](http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/2.0/)
- [Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/)

You can start from reading what a web service is:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service

Also some links which provide example of accessing web services from android:

- [Step by step to access web service from android](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/112381/Step-by-Step-Method-to-Access-Webservice-from-Andr)
- [Android and soap web services](http://p-xr.com/android-development-tutorial-reading-soap-services/)
- [Accessing restfull web service with android](http://www.josecgomez.com/2010/04/30/android-accessing-restfull-web-services-using-json/)

Comment: Not sure what the OP was looking for, but I was hoping for some advice on how to architect a similar project. I tried using SOAP but I couldn't get XML parsing to work in the android framework? All the libraries I tried to use were unwieldy or depended on things I could not import.

Comment: @Yamikuronue IMHO SOAP is too slow. I'm successfully using [Apache Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/) in an Android SQLite <-> PostgreSQL remote DB synchronization project and works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Another and much easier approach is to use a Virtual JDBC Driver that relys on a secured three-tier architecture: your JDBC code is sent through HTTP to a remote Servlet that filters the JDBC code (configuration & security) before passing it to the MySql JDBC Driver. The result is sent you back through HTTP.

There are some free software that use this technique. Just Google "Android JDBC Driver over HTTP".

Answer (score -1):

You would have to keep a middle tier online server.Which may communicate to and fro between your application and MSSQL db.May be servlet or a request handler which synchronises between the SQLite and SQL Server db.