# Can't connect to android database

Tags: java, android, mysql, database, jtds

I am attempting to connect to an Azure database via an android app I am creating, however I keep getting this particular error: 
`Network error IOException: Could not create socket`.

I can connect to the database on my login activity successfully, but if I reuse the same code on a different activity it will not connect at all.

I have attempted to reformat the connection string, but the problem persists. This is my current code to connect which is the same in the Login Activity:

```
String username = "username";
String password = "password";
String host = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://databaseUrl:1433/database"

try {
        Class.forName("net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Connecting to database for duty...");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(host, username, password);
        System.out.println("connected");
} catch (SQLException err) {
        System.err.println(err.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Connecting directly to a remote database from an Android app [is generally a **very** bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26471486/469080)

Comment: I do not know if it is possible to directly connect to a Databse Server from Android. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3492417/connect-to-sql-server-from-android

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428(v=sql.110).aspx
host sould be in this format:
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<databaseUrl>\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=database;user=username;password=password;
But this is a bad idea to do.