# Connecting Android Application with any Database

Tags: android

How would i go on connecting my Android application with my local database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest way is to use something like PHP as a middle layer, then send HTTP requests from your Android application to it. Take a look at [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) for more information

Also read this: [how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419697/how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server)

Hope this helps.