# Database in Android

Tags: android

My application needs a database. The database contains only one table i.e. for password. Password will be inserted only one time, and there's no need for delete and upgrade. Can anybody help for code? For this password database, user will insert only one time, and database will be closed. And when the user inserts next time, the password will be checked against the database password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use `SharedPreferences` for storing only one field??

Encrypt the password before saving in `SharedPreferences` whose mode is set to `MODE_PRIVATE`, and whenever you have to check , just encrypt the text user had typed, and match with `SharedPreferences`

This way, you'll be in ease.

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) and [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

Comment: sorry for my english,just i taken password from user in edit text,and how to encrypt this text string,pls help how to use this exact i m newbie in Android Development

Comment: you can check this out: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#encodeToString%28byte[],%20int,%20int,%20int%29
Convert your password string to a byte[] array and feed that array to this method, you'll get the encrypted String back

Answer (score 1):

An excellent tutorial at DEVX [Creating and Using Databases in Android](http://www.devx.com/wireless/Article/40842/1954)

Answer (score 1):

This can be the duplicate of: [connecting-android-application-with-any-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791569/connecting-android-application-with-any-database/)

***The answer is:***

Probably the easiest way is to use something like PHP as a middle layer, then send HTTP requests from your Android application to it. Take a look at [this](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database) for more information

Also read this: [how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419697/how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need it for a single table, containing a single row, then are you sure a database is the right choice?  I think saving the password to `SharedPreferences` might be a better fit.  Have a look at the [data storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) options.