# Connect to SQL Server and show data in the app

Tags: android, sql-server, select

I have SQL Server 2008 R2 with a table that contains data ordered by numbers from 1 to 99999.

I want to connect to that table and show the last number of the row in my app, automatically without selecting anything.

How I could do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot do anyting without performing a select statement. Sorry

Comment: You can use the following select statement `Select MAX(MyNumberColumn) FROM MyTable`

Comment: Are you saying that you want to connect to a table in a SQL Server instance on a PC based machine FROM an Android app?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to connect android to a database server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419697/how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server)

Answer (score 2):

If you will connect to the server from your Android App I would recommend using a webservice.

Take a look at this for example:

[Rest Webservice](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/cc950529)

And you don't want to select anything? You can call a Stored Procedure maybe?

Answer (score 1):

The SQL:

```
select top 1 from yourtable order by yournumericfield desc;
```

Or

```
select max(yournumericfield) from yourtable;
```

I notice that this is tagged Android. Android cannot talk directly with SQL Server. The easiest thing to do is to write a web service to sit in between the Android device and SQL Server:

Android --> Web Service -> SQL Server

You can perform standard HTTP communication in Java to talk to the web service. Your web service can talk to SQL Server using ADO in C++, or using the DB libraries in C#, perhaps. Or easier, using a web scripting language like ASP or ASP.NET, you can use the standard Windows DB functions.