# Connect to remote database

Tags: android

I am developing an application for Android that runs a PHP file on the server. PHP file in which there is a connection with a connection to remote database and selecting SQL commands. In addition I have a Listview in my MainActivity that when I click on an item in the list represents ask other activity statements of my command SQL data. If I click on another item , the information changes.ç

I tried to do it with a AsyncTask and Thread.

How can I do this?? Can somebody help me?

**Updated**

Yes, I get the data in JSON format.

I want to do this:

> Main Activity --> Background Process --> Second activity --> Click Item_List -> Process data in JSON format -> Represents on a second activity the information

I need to know how to do the background process (service, asynctask, thread)

The select have a WHERE clause that depends on the item clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Is not secure to connect an Android application directly to SQL server, you should create a web page that contains the data you need in a parsable format, like JSON. 
You find a good guide here: [How to connect Android to a database server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419697/how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server)