# Class DriverManager has errors when trying to import VMStack and CallerSensitive

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jdbc, classnotfound

I am new to Android Studio and I don't have that much experience in Java.

I installed the latest Android Studio version on a MacBook and everything worked fine (I also ran simple apps and worked flawlessly) until I had to use the class DriverManager to connect to a mysql database. When the program tries to call the DriverManager.getConnection() it pauses endlessly without throwing exceptions.

So I opened the class DriverManager and found out it had errors. In particular it's trying to do these two imports:

```
import dalvik.system.VMStack;
import sun.reflect.CallerSensitive;
```

but both classes do not exist in the specified path nor anywhere else.

I tried re-installing Android Studio and downloading many different versions of the SDK from the SDK manager but nothing solves the problem and I cannot find anything on the web. I only read somewhere around that VMStack is deprecated.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

[Here's also a screenshot of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwO7e.png)

Comment: Getting a stack trace is usually the first port of call if there's a hang.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3419697/how-to-connect-android-to-a-database-server

Answer (score 1):

First off-  you should never connect directly to a db from a phone app.  Doing so means your password is at best in RAM, at worst in your actual app, which means your db is compromised.  Always use a webservice to abstract away db access.

Second-  you aren't compiling Driver manager, so any errors you see in the IDE are invalid.  It isn't working with the full source.

Third-  to debug what your actual problem is, we'd need code.  But like I said in 1, you shouldn't ever be doing this anyway.

Comment: Could be a local database.

Comment: @TomHawtin-tackline On Android?  So they'd be circumventing the entirte android os and installing a db directly on the underlying linux OS, and managing it that way?  Extremely unlikely.  And if you're talking about something like a SQLite or similar db, there's better ways to access it than JDBC.  Also it wouldn't work at all as a standalong playstore app, because there's no real way to bundle a separate db executable like that.  Yeah, unlikely enough that I'm going to ignore the possibility.

Comment: Thank you. At the moment I'll be doing tests on a local database but in the future this is supposed to work on a remote db, so I'd definitely go for another option.