# Client/server database for android tutorial needed

Tags: android, database, http, client-server, android-sqlite

Hope everyone's doing great;

What is the best client/server application to use with database for android?

I know the implementation of database with Java very well. Should I use MySQL, Oracle or Access for example or should I use SQLite Database if I need to access it via server over internet?

I wasn't advised to use JDBC at all; In other way, I was advised to connect to the database via HTTP request. But isn't SQLite Database a local one only available on the host?

Any ideas or is there any good tutorial about it? I'm a bit confused..

Thanks in advance and best
regards,
Chris

Comment: Go with MySQL,PHP and android. Access MySQL database by PHP. Access php by Http request in android.

Comment: @selva_pollachi- if we can access the PHP by simple HTTP request, anyone can do an HTTP request and modify our database. (Have heard of it) So isn't that should be encrypted for safety?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seems completely confused.

On the client side (Android app), you can use [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html) to store data locally. It might not be necessary at all actually. For instance, it can be used for offline features, search, etc.

On the server side (whatever server side technology you know or want to learn), you can use whatever language, whatever database on whatever server OS you want. This part is commonly called the back-end, which will store your data while your app communicate with it through HTTP.

Comment: lol actually I am!
Ok, I got what you said thanks a lot. Is there any good tutorial about communication between the android app and HTTP?
If it isn't via HTTP, can I connect the client and the server with a wireless ad-hoc or is it a stupid idea?

Comment: I feel you are mixing two things, how to communicate and on what hardware, technology and protocol. Of course you can communicate with wireless ad-hoc but then one of your devices should run a http server (like apache) if you want to send it http requests. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model

Comment: I know it's a late reply, I was searching in my previous questions and found this one unanswered..

I ended up installing "wampserver" on the server side and communicating with it via HTTP request along with JSON parser.
And for the offline features i'm using SQLite database.

Accepted your answer because it helped me a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

this answer could help you  :
[Best way to implement Client <-> Server <-> Database architecture in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256082/best-way-to-implement-client-server-database-architecture-in-an-android)
And this tutorial about webservice :
http://jatin4rise.wordpress.com/2010/10/03/webservicecallfromandroid/

Comment: I already checked this answer but didn't completely know where to begin actually.. 
Will check this tutorial and give my feedback..
Thanks a lot for your quick reply